Merge duplicate unique values in googlesheets
Trying to merge duplicate entries to find the first-nonblank value for each column for a given ID while joining any non-blank unique values in the same column



ID
Occurence
Name
Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
Field5




A
1
john
a

b
c



A
2
john


c

e


A
3
john


c




B
1
mary
a
b
c
d
e


B
2
mary
a
b
c




C
1
sara
a
b
c
d
e



For example, in a list where there are three entries for john (ID=A2:A4) unique values are outputed for B2:H where col1=A
Essentially for each unique value in A:A a column a formula similar to this is applied `textjoin("~", 1, unique(B2:B4))
Output



ID
Occurence
Name
Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
Field5




A
1~2~3
john
a

b~c
c
e


B
1~1
mary
a
b
b
c



C
1
sara
a
b
c
d
e





You may try:
=map(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,hstack(Σ,bycol(filter(B:H,A:A=Σ),lambda(Λ,textjoin("~",1,unique(Λ)))))))



Output mismatching with your expected result for ID: B


Here's a possible solution:
=MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),LAMBDA(id,{id,BYCOL(FILTER(B2:H,A2:A=id),LAMBDA(c,TEXTJOIN("~",1,UNIQUE(c))))}))

We are filtering the values for each unique ID, taking the unique values by column and joining them together.


whoops, that's the exact same solution of rockinfreakshow, for some reason their answer didn't appear to me before I posted.

this has advantage of being more readable but both appear to acheive same result.
